# How To dump data from Oracle to Vertica

Tags: oracle, vertica

I want to transfer data from Oracle to Vertica and I want to know what is best way to do it?
I s there a tool for it?

I tried to dump the Oracle data and load it to Vertica using '`Copy Direct`' command but I fount lots of problems specially in the data and timestamps columns.

Comment: What date/timestamp formats is Vertica expecting? Can you edit your question with an example, along with what methods you've tried to dump the data from Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

Try to export the data into `csv` format, and recreate the table in Vertica using the DDL from Oracle. Check the types as they differ from Oracle to Vertica.

Example: assuming the following table structure on Oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE PEOPLE
(
    ID NUMBER (10),
    NAME VARCHAR2 (50),
    ADDRESS VARCHAR2 (250),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

Assuming a compatible table structure on Vertica:

```
CREATE TABLE PEOPLE
(
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL    /*ORACLE datatype: NUMBER(10, 0)  */,
    NAME VARCHAR(50)      /*ORACLE datatype: VARCHAR2(50)   */,
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(250)  /*ORACLE datatype: VARCHAR2(250)  */,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Load the table content using the copy command in Vertica:

```
copy "table name" from 'full csv file path'
    delimiter ',' null as '' exceptions 'full error file path';
```

Done!