# how to find vertica community edition and how to export / copy data

Tags: distributed-databases, vertica

I have the hardest time downloading anything other than enterprise edition from vertica.com. It is supposed to have a community edition on https://my.vertica.com/community/ but all the links just show the enterprise editions for download.

I have an older download (forgot how I got to that earlier) vertica-ce-6.0.1-0.x86_64.RHEL5.rpm which may be the latest, not sure, enterprise edition latest seems to be 6.1.0 at the time of writing.

I installed that and pushed 12 million rows to it from an older enterprise edition version using CONNECT TO VERTICA and EXPORT TO VERTICA... however when I tried to now push that data out from the community edition to another test installation that also is community edition, psql says:

ERROR 2678:  Command EXPORT is not supported

Googling that brings up nothing, and the my.vertica.com forums also have no match. Am I the first to see it really?

Whats the next efficient way to dump the data from one community edition vertica installation to another if EXPORT TO VERTICA and COPY FROM VERTICA should not be supported in the community edition?

The reason why I am looking at vertica is that it appears to respond much faster than mysql when there are more than a billion rows in the table, i.e. the result set of a query comes in within 30 seconds instead of 5 minutes on identical hardware.

Comment: Give up on MySQL instead of coming here to ask for tuning help? Odd decision.

Comment: I edited my question to make the reason clearer... there are 1.2 billion rows in the table to analyze. Still think it is just a tuning question for mysql?

Comment: A properly designed and indexed database doesn't require something like Vertica. Ask for help here and you will get it. If the answers are "give up and go with a no-sql approach", then do it. Vertica is expensive. We're here to help :)

Comment: Phil: one of my stronger database servers with mysql 5.1 in a master/slave setup with binlog-sync can process 100,000 inserts with mysqlslap in something under a minute. mariadb 5.5 can do that in about 10 seconds. If I try to do the same with 100 million rows, how long will it take? Hint: The answer is NOT 1000 minutes for mysql 5.1. Try it out for yourself and let me know how you tuned this to run in a reasonable amount of time, I am always eager to learn.

Comment: Take a look at this link 
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23412/how-to-dump-data-from-oracle-to-vertica

Answer (score 3):

HP Vertica has their community edition for download at https://my.vertica.com/download-community-edition/. If you don't have one already, you will be prompted to create a MyVertica login. If you have problems creating a login, please email me at dsandahl@vertica.com. If you have further issues loading your data, you can tweet at @VerticaHelp and support will follow up with you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to support a DW/BI type of workload, MySQL won't come close to the performance you'll get with Vertica, both in terms of analytical query response times and load times.  Upgrading to 6.1 from 6.0 is a good choice...there were a few bugs in 6.0 that are fixed in 6.1.

Vertica is not a NoSQL solution...it's an ANSI-SQL compliant columnar RDBMS designed to do two things extrememly well...1) deliver blistering fast analytical query response times and 2) load data mind-bogglingly fast. The community edition is free for 1Tb and 3 nodes, and the commercial version isn't that expensive either.  There's no PostgreSQL code in it, but it's organized much like Postgres (which is not surprising since it came from the mind of Dr. Michael Stonebraker). It's an excellent, well-done product. ;-)

Comment: Forgot to answer one part...in cases where export/connect isn't supported, you can use the vsql client to dump the data to a CSV file, then just COPY the CSV file into the new database.  vsql -w [your password] -A -t -c 'SELECT * FROM your_table;' | gzip > /s3mnt/vertica_backup/event_fact_snapshot will give you a gzipped vertical bar delimited txt file, which you can then COPY with the GZIP DELIMITER '|' command options.

Comment: Do you have any commercial affiliation with Vertica?

Answer (score 0):

The Enterprise and the Community editions are now binary equal. Go for the Enterprise edition. Not setting a license willswitch it to a "Community Edition".

Check the documentation specially for COPY as suggested.